# Can anyone help me understand why I can't compile this code?

Tags: compiler-errors

Can anyone help me understand why I can't compile this code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
    static void imprimirSequencia(int n){
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            System.out.println(n + " ");

        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    imprimirSequencia(15);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting a compiler error with your code, maybe it's a problem with your IDE.